# File size always remains same as 12288 bytes for small files 

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am using `Wp7IsolatedStorageExplorer` to get some small files (say max `20 bytes`) stored in IsolatedStorage.But every time I download file the Filesize remains  `12288 bytes`(for small files) .Is `IsolatedStorageExplorer` appending something at last OR Is it How small Files are stored in `IsolatedStorage` by default ?

Thanks

vaysage.

Comment: So much for "640k ought to be enough for anybody."

Comment: if you look in the downloaded file, what is there after the 20 bytes you put in?

Comment: Interesting - that sounds like a FAT file system block - 0x3000 bytes. FAT file systems normally work in blocks of 0x1000 (4096 bytes) - which is why they are not good for storing lots of small files. My guess is that WP7 must be using some modification of FAT/TFAT which uses 0x3000 size blocks - but this is only a guess. When you view the file in an app is it actually 20 bytes long? (i.e. is the rest just unused space?)

Comment: @Matt Lacey it is filled with null characters after the 20 bytes.

Comment: @Stuart From trial and error I found that ,the files are stored in multiples of 12kb. So a file less than 12 kb will always be 12kb ,a file with 13 kb will be 24kb and so on. I guess  `WP7IsolatedStorageExplorer` is the culprit.When i view the file in app its just taking the same space(20 bytes in my case).So i guess it may not be a problem with isolatedstorage .What is your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially I thought this might be an indication of the underlying FAT implementation.

However, having looked a bit deeper and having looked at your answers to comments, my guess is that this is just a UI issue in the IsolatedStorageExplorer - if you look at the source http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/63791#1114123 - then it seems to use 12288 as a chunk size for its networking layers.

Comment: Thanks :) ,Perfect answer.Can I ask one doubt,How you have found such a small thing in such a big code.

Comment: I just went to the codeplex site and had a look at the code in the library section - I'm sure if you download the source, then you could also do a "Find In Files" for 12288 - I reckon you'd find it in at least a couple of places.